# I'm trying to code a random number generator for poker but I keep getting an exception

Tags: python

I am trying to recreate poker in Python and I'm trying to move cards from 2 lists, the `deckNumber` and `deckSuit` lists, into `playerHand` and I'm getting an "empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)" error when using `randint` in line 11.

```
import random

deckNumber = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
deckSuit = ["Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts"]
playerHand = []
oppHand = []

for i in range(5):
    number = deckNumber.pop(random.randint(0, len(deckNumber)-1))
    suit = deckSuit.pop(random.randint(0, len(deckSuit)-1))
    playerHand.append(number + " " + suit)

    print(playerHand)
```

I've tried putting another number between 0 and `len(deckSuit)-1` but then it says I'm using 4 inputs instead of 3. I've also tried doing `len(deckSuit)-2` and just `len(deckSuit)`, but `len(deckSuit)` gives me an "out of range" error and `len(deckSuit)-2` gives me the "empty range" error.

Comment: If you include line numbers within the code, we can't copy and run it in order to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Why do you want to remove an item 5 times from `deckSuit`, which only contains 4 items?

Comment: Sorry about the line numbers, I didnt realize that would happen if I added those, wanted to make it easier to read, also mkrieger, that was the problem! thank you a lot, it was frustrating me for a couple days now and I didnt think it was such a simple fix

Comment: Using Stack Overflow as an interactive debugger is notoriously inefficient. Instead, find and learn to use whatever [debugger](/q/25385173/90527) your development suite provides. At that point, if you encounter a problem you can't solve you can then post a question about that specific issue with a [mcve]. See "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)" Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article.